# An inverse spectrum problem in linear algebra,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

I am reading the book, *Nonnegative Matrices*, by Henryk Minc, and came across an exercise that I would like to solve:

Let $$\bar \sigma = (\bar\lambda_1, ... , \bar \lambda_n)=(\lambda_1, ... \lambda_n) = \sigma $$

and

$$\max_i |\lambda_i| \in \sigma$$

Now, consider only the case $n=2$.

I want to show that there exists an entry-wise non-negative matrix of the form

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        b & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

with $\sigma = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ as its spectrum.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Edit: I have also read the paper "The nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem" by Patricia Egleston, Terry Lanker and Sivaram Narayan.  I am trying to solve the above problem, for the case n=2, which is supposed to be a nice, easy, warm-up to understanding the paper and the mathematical problem a bit better.

And, if this is a question that is more suitable for mathoverflow.net, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help and guidance of @user1551, the desired matrix is

$$ \large
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac {\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} & \frac {\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\\
        \frac {\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2} & \frac {\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Please see the comments below, if you wish to compute this matrix, too.

Thanks,

Comment: There is no case 3. As $\max_i |\lambda_i| \in \sigma$. So, you may assume (by relabelling the $\lambda_i$s if necessary) that $\lambda_1=\max_i |\lambda_i| \in \sigma$. Therefore, when $n=2$, we must have $\lambda_1\ge0$ and $|\lambda_2|\le\lambda_1$. Furthermore, as $\bar\sigma=\sigma$, $\lambda_2$ must be real.

Comment: Hi @user1551, thanks for your comment; I follow your argument but am not sure how to proceed, since $\lambda_2$ can be negative and still be smaller than $\lambda_1$ in absolute value -- a diagonal matrix with $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ on the diagonal would not be entry-wise non-negative and hence wouldn't be the matrix that solves the inverse problem.  And also, in writing this comment, I have just realized that the matrix I gave for what I thought was the trivial Case 1 ... is also not correct, since I need the matrix to have constant main diagonal and constant anti-diagonal...

Comment: Just find the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&a}$ and you'll see how to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @user1551 hmm...ok, I found the eigenvalues, which are just $\lambda_1 = (a+b)$ and $\lambda_2 = (a-b)$.  So...to solve the inverse problem, given an arbitrary list of length 2, $\sigma = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ and assuming that it satisfies the two assumptions, then are you saying that it *must* be in the form of (a+b,  a-b), which would be the spectrum of the matrix with constant main / anti-diagonals.  I don't see why the eigenvalues must be in this form, though, even after using the two assumptions...

Comment: What we want is to find *some* $a,b$ such that $\lambda_1=a+b$ and $\lambda_2=a-b$. Can you solve for $a$ and $b$ with these two equations? Do you see that $a$ and $b$ are always nonnegative?

Comment: Hi @user1551, thanks for your patience.  I have solved for $a$ and $b$, and I get the matrix as $$ \large
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} &  \frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\\
       \frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2} &  \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$  ... the last thing is to justify why the values of $a$ and $b$ are always nonnegative...which I don't immediately see...

Comment: I am trying to see whether the two assumptions would force $a$ and $b$ to be nonnegative... @user1551 ...

Comment: Recall that the given conditions imply that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are real, and we have relabelled the eigenvalues so that $0\le|\lambda_2|\le\lambda_1$.

Comment: Ah, ok I got it all now, I think.  Thanks so much for your help and patience, @user1551 :-)

Comment: Hi @user1551, I want to show the existence of this matrix, without the assumption that it has structure to it -- and then to see that it turns out to be symmetric anyway.  But I am struggling to do so.  Starting with a list of 2 real numbers (I have already showed that lists of complex numbers are not realizable by $2\times 2$ nonnegative matrices),

Comment: I have been looking at the characteristic polynomial, setting it to zero, and also trying to find systems of equations that would be make it apparent that the realizing matrix must be symmetric, thus showing that the symmetric inverse eigenvalue problem (SNIEP) and the real nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem (RNIEP) are actually equivalent for the case n=2.  What do you think I should do?  The original question I posted was relatively easy, from knowing that the matrix was symmetric from the start, and I could back out the desired matrix.  Thanks, @user1551

Comment: No, the realising matrix is not necessarily symmetric. Every 2x2 asymmetric nonnegative matrix will realise some real spectrum. E.g. $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ has spectrum $\{1,1\}$. It just happens that when $n=2$, every spectrum of a nonnegative matrix is realisable by some symmetric nonnegative matrix.

Comment: Hi @user1551, ah, ok, I got it.  Can I please squeeze in one more question if you don't mind?  How could I show that an arbitrary list of two real numbers is realizable by some nonnegative matrix -- not necessarily symmetric?  With the symmetric constraint, finding the 2 eigenvalues, obtaining 2 equations, and then solving for the entries of the matrix was very nice.  But without the symmetric constraint, I look at the matrix, its characteristic polynomial, use the quadratic formula,

Comment: and see how the eigenvalues like it (and that the prescribed list of numbers, in order for it to be the spectrum of the matrix, must have that form).  But this is of course pretty nasty.  The eigenvalues look like $\large \frac {(a+d) +/- \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4bc}}{2}$.  There are now four variables $a,b,c,d$ to solve for, in order to construct the desired matrix.  How could I show this, @user1551?

Comment: I also tried using the fact that if the list were the spectrum, then the sum of the numbers must be the trace of the matrix, and the product of the numbers must be the determinant of the matrix, but so far I am not able to progress any further.  What do you think?  Thanks @user1551,